# awk script for coverting BibTeX to XHTML

Tags: bibtex, conversion, tools, html

I found several nawk and gawk scripts scattered all over the Internet for converting BibTeX files to HTML mostly written in 90s. A quick look into source code indicates, not surprisingly, that some of them will not produce valid XHTML 1.0 strict tags. Before I try to clear up somebody's nawk script (I do not use gawk) can anyone recommend me a script which works well from your own experience? I am OK with gawk as long as I do not have to fix anything. I would also consider a nice Perl or Python script. I must shamefully admit that I have not investigated Perl and Python solutions properly.

Comment: As phrased, I'm worried that this is borderline for off-topic. It's not clear how expertise in TeX or BibTeX would help with the question posed, which is about awk.

Answer (score 6):

Biber aims eventually to deal with such cases. At the moment (as of version 0.9.8), you can use the `--bltxml` option to ouput a BibLaTeXML file instead of a `.bbl`. BibLaTeXML is experimental still but it's XML with a defined schema so converting this to HTML is likely to be much easier than from `.bib` format directly, using XSLT. This is generally a better approach as the actual HTML output will vary a lot depending on what you want it to look like exactly.